# Help with workflow on SP2010 designer

Tags: workflow, tasks

This has been bugging me for sometime and now with a important deadline tonight i need to find a solution to my Workflow issues. I have 2 workflows i need to construct and through all my testing and designer none of my steps are working.

I am kind of new to SP2010 admin - so forgive me if these seem basic.

WF1: To send a notifcation as to when a discussion thread has been updated to the author only after sending to a group to tell them a new thread is there.

So step 1: Email group when created
Step 2: When modified by that group , email author - this has been falling over

WF2: Reminder to Task if not completed
Now i have tried hundreds of different wf's and none seem to work, the sticky wicket is the pause. I can set the pause to 1min and still no reminder. The current WF for this is:

Pause for 0 days , 0 hours, 0 minutes

then Wait for Status to not equal Completed

then Email {User}

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Many Thanks

DM

Answer (score 1):

For WF1, you should consider creating a variable and setting it to the author of the original thread. Then you can use that value to send the reply emails to. That way, the value of "creator" isn't overwritten when a reply to the thread is done.

For WF2, the pausing of a workflow for a time period relies on the workflow timer job that runs in the farm. You need to verify how often this timer job is running, and set your pause no shorter than that. You should also be aware that if you set it to a date, it generally will be sent out around midnight on that date.

Answer (score 0):

WF2: my guess is that your issue is with "Wait for Status to not equal Completed", because the workflow will wait for the status to change.

Instead, try this:
if status is equal to completed then stop workflow else send reminder